# Spring Boot // Keycloak HTTPS : Could not obtain the keys oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder

Tags: spring-security, https, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot App that communicates with a keycloak server secured with SSL certificates issued by LetsEncrypt.
When I try to validate the JWT that was given by said keycloak server i get this stack error

```
2022-09-27 09:55:31.150 ERROR 4076 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [169594fc-2]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/<MYENDPOINT>"

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain the keys
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder.lambda$processor$6(NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.java:398) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/<MYENDPOINT>" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder.lambda$processor$6(NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.java:398) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3733) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        
    / .... redacted because too many characters .... /

        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://<MY DOMAIN>/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        / .... redacted because too many characters .... /
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369) ~[na:na]
    / .... redacted because too many characters .... /
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335) ~[na:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

2022-09-27 09:55:31.159  WARN 4076 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [72bd1d07, L:/<IP>:38266 - R:<MY DOMAIN>/<IP>:443] The connection observed an error

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[na:na]
    / .... redacted because too many characters .... /
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335) ~[na:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

2022-09-27 09:55:31.161  WARN 4076 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [72bd1d07, L:/<IP>:38266 ! R:<MY DOMAIN>/<IP>:443] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:480) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:425) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1068) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1015) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1548) ~[netty-handler-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1394) ~[netty-handler-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235) ~[netty-handler-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284) ~[netty-handler-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335) ~[na:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Some suggestions on the internet said that I should add my certificate to the $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts , and I did that but still the same issue.

This is my application.yml file with the keycloak conf:

```
  main:
    banner-mode: off
    allow-circular-references: true
    web-application-type: reactive
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://<MY DOMAIN>/realms/master
          jwk-set-uri: https://<MY DOMAIN>/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            realm: master
            client-id: <MY CLIENT ID>
            client-secret: <MY SECRET>
            scope: openid, profile, email, roles
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: https://<MY DOMAIN>/realms/master
            token-uri: https://<MY DOMAIN>/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

And here is my ReactiveSecurityConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class ReactiveSecurityConfig {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ROLES_CLAIM = "resource_access";

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers("/*").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                        .anyExchange().authenticated().and().oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverterForKeycloak()))
                    )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .build();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverterForKeycloak() {
        Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwt -> {
            //Map<String, Collection<String>> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim("realm_access");
            var resourceAccess = jwt.getClaimAsMap("resource_access");

            //Collection<String> roles = realmAccess.get("roles");
            var resourceRoles = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.get("<MY CLIENT ID>);
            var roles = (Collection<String>) resourceRoles.get("roles");

            return roles.stream()
                    .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        };

        var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(
                new ReactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter));
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;

    }

    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "java:S5411"})
    GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return authorities -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            var authority = authorities.iterator().next();
            boolean isOidc = authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority;


            if (isOidc) {
                var oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                var userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();

                if (userInfo.containsClaim(RESOURCE_ROLES_CLAIM)) {
                    var resourceAccess = userInfo.getClaimAsMap(RESOURCE_ROLES_CLAIM);
                    var resourceRoles = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.get("<MY CLIENT ID>");
                    var roles = (Collection<String>) resourceRoles.get("roles");
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(roles));
                }

            } else {
                var oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority) authority;
                Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

                if (userAttributes.containsKey(RESOURCE_ROLES_CLAIM)) {
                    var roles = (Collection<String>) userAttributes.get(RESOURCE_ROLES_CLAIM);
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(roles));
                }
            }


            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(Collection<String> roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository reactiveClientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientProperties oAuth2ClientProperties) {

        List<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations = new ArrayList<>();

        // because autoconfigure does not work for an unknown reason, here the ClientRegistrations are manually configured based on the application.yml
        oAuth2ClientProperties.getRegistration()
                .forEach((k, v) -> {
                    String tokenUri = oAuth2ClientProperties.getProvider().get(k).getTokenUri();
                    ClientRegistration clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
                            .withRegistrationId(k)
                            .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                            .clientId(v.getClientId())
                            .clientSecret(v.getClientSecret())
                            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                            .build();
                    clientRegistrations.add(clientRegistration);
                });

        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrations);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to add a "production" certificate from Let's encrypt to cacerts. I see a few possibilities for failure:

- Keycloak is misconfigured, does not find Let's Encrypt certificate, and uses a self-signed one. To check that, check SSL certificate content (click the lock next to the URL when you visit Keycloak admin console)
- You have several JDKs / JREs on your machine, added the "staging" certificate to the cacerts of one and run your Spring app with another (check in the run configuration which is used). When your spring-boot app at starts, **what is the first log line?**
- You have several Let's Encrypt certificate at hand (a "production" one and a few "staging others", configured Keycloak with one and your cacerts with another
- The certificate was emitted for one hostname (visible in the details you got at first step) and you configured Spring with another (even if DNS has several entries for the same host, you should use the hostname declared in the certificate)
- You are using a very deprecated java version (with no or expired root certificate for Let's encrypt)

Comment: - I have the little padlock to the left of my url in my keycloak domain, I made sure I am using the right certificates, those from letsencrypt
- I do have several JDKs but i am sure I put the certificates in the right one.
- I have one certificates from letsencrypt.
- I am sure I certified the right domain name and keycloak is in the same domain.

I did make some of these mistakes in the past thats why this time that I made sure everything is alright It's bugging me. Thnk you for your answer.

Comment: I do have a question @ch4mp:  

*__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://<MY DOMAIN>/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs [DefaultWebClient]

this line in the error stack worries me because this endpoint for me from the navigator is working why doesn't it work from spring boot ?

Comment: Your web browser has a different set of trusted certificates than the JRE your Spring app runs with. Maybe are you using a pretty old JDK? What is the very first log line of your Spring-boot app at startup (after logo)? (I edited my answer to add this question)

Comment: Starting App using Java 11.0.15,  it is this same jdk where i put the certs, sorry my response took so long

Answer (score 0):

You can disable HTTPS certificate validation by overriding default ReactiveJwtDecoder bean:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = {
            "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri",
            "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.useInsecureTrustManager"
    })
    ReactiveJwtDecoder insecureJwtDecoder(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties) {
        var jwtDecoder = NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder
                .withJwkSetUri(properties.getJwt().getJwkSetUri())
                .jwsAlgorithms(algorithms -> algorithms.add(SignatureAlgorithm.from("RS256")))
                .webClient(InsecureWebClient.getInstance())
                .build();
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(JwtValidators.createDefault());
        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

and passing insecure WebClient to the decoder builder:

```
public class InsecureWebClient {
    @SneakyThrows
    public static WebClient getInstance() {
        var sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
        var httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(b -> b.sslContext(sslContext));
        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
    }
}
```

And then update you application.yml:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.useInsecureTrustManager: true
```